# What's the term for a word which contains an affix?

Tags: terminology, morphology

From my basic lay understanding of non-polysynthetic linguistics (and [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/19220/21520)), a word may be either:

- #1. A single root (or "stem" or "base") morpheme; or
- #2. One or more affixes combined with a root.

Is there a more specific term for a word of the #2 type? For example, the word "enjoy" would be an instance of that term, but the word "joy" would not.

[An existing english.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197941/terminology-for-a-word-containing-a-prefix-suffix-or-neither) question asks almost the same thing, but its answer is that #1 is a root and #2 is a root plus affix(es), which doesn't quite answer my question. I'm looking for a term that specifically means #2.

Comment: Derivation or inflection, I'd say

Comment: I think this depends on the theoretical framework you're working under or, in some cases, the researcher you're talking to. For instance, I understand _base_ to be a general term for roots and stems, a _root_ to be a free morpheme with no affixation, and a _stem_ to be a root with any combination of affixes attached. Another linguist may very well think of these terms differently, especially if they're working under a different theoretical framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are appropriate adjectives, but not nouns: "joy" is monomorphemic, "enjoy" is polymorphemic (under a liberal interpretation of English morphology). Other words like derivation, inflection etc. refer to the morphological process, but not the product of a morphological process (or its lack, in the case of an underived / monomorphemic root). Also note that an answer from English SE is likely to only consider the kinds of morphology found in English, and in many languages, roots are not even words.

Comment: This is the clearest answer, but jknappen's answer is ideal for any reader looking for more info.

Answer (score 7):

There are several common terms in use, e.g. monomorphemic or [**simplex**](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Simplex) words, and polymorphemic or **complex** words; cf. the screenshot below from [The Oxford Handbook of the Word](http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199641604.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199641604) (from [the article](http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199641604.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199641604-e-002) written by [Geert Booij](https://geertbooij.com/)):

[image]

Incidentally, I would analyze enjoy as a simplex word, at least synchronically in (Modern) English; see the screenshot above.

Comment: Also _enlighten, lighten, redden, blacken,_ and _soften_?

Comment: @jlawler redden, blacken, soften: ADJ+en, suffix; lighten (and its derivative enlighten): N+en, suffix.

Comment: The causative/inchoative prefix _en-_ and the  causative/inchoative  suffix _-en_ are no longer productive. There are lots of _-en_ words, as you note, but there are lots of _en-_ words, too. Here's 18 that start with _em-_: _embalm
embargo
embark
embattled
embed
embellish
embezzle
embitter
emblazon
embody
embolden
emboss
embrace
embrasure
embroider
embroil
employ
empower_. There isn't room for the 51 others that start with _en-_, like _ensure, enforce, engrave, enlist, enroll,_ and _enslave_.

Comment: @jlawler some of the 51 words you mention are irrelevant, e.g. ensure (en+ADJ); some are somewhat questionable, e.g. OED says enforce and enroll were borrowed as such etc.

Comment: @jlawler also note that I originally wrote "synchronically in (Modern) English" in my answer - cf. yours "The causative/inchoative prefix en- and the causative/inchoative suffix -en **are no longer productive**" [emphasis mine - A.B.].

Comment: @jlawler enrage or empower would be the best examples within a subgroup, imho (en+N).

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of terminology floating around that.

First, the basics: There are *word forms* occurring in real life. A word form belongs to a *lemma* that is a canonical word form relating to some other forms (e.g., for the lemma "have" there are the word forms "have", "having", "has", and "had"). Then, there is a *stem* that is generated off a word form by cutting some affixes. All those terms relate to basic morphology (there is not a lot of it left in English, other languages have a much richer morphology). Note that one lemma can have several (more or less obviously) related stems, like Latin scribere, scribo, scripsi, scriptum exhibiting three stems (present, perfect, and supine stem).

Morphemes come into play when you consider semantics. Derivational morphology and composition are means of creating word forms (and even stems) containing more than one morpheme. A word form containing only one morpheme is called *monomorphemic*. With two morphemes, it is *dimorphemic* and so on. As an opposite of monomorphemic, the term *polymorphemic* can be used.

You can also put your focus on word formation, than you find that a word is *suffixed* (only rarely *suffigated*, has a suffix attached), *prefixed* (with a prefix), *infixed* (with an infix), or just *affixed* (with an unspecified affix).

Comment: imho **bimorphemic** is more common than dimorphemic in morphological research.

Comment: Interesting forms, the ones I'm familiar with are: suffixed, prefixed, infixed, affixed.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut  you're absolutely right. All those words, suffigated etc. are extremely rare in English, unlike in German or Russian linguistics.

Comment: @AlexB.: I thought about bimorphemic, too, but than I decided for dimorphemic because it is a Greek-Greek formation while bimorphemic is Latin-Greek.

Comment: IMHO this answer covers it but is just missing the actual string *polymorphemic*.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Don’t you find the terms in this answer extremely unusual? E.g. lemma is common in lexicographic research, perhaps computational linguistics, but **not** in morphology. See also suffigated etc.

Comment: @AlexB. Coming from a corrupt industry background, *lemma* and *lemmatisation* fall under what is known to me as *morphology*.  It's used by Univ. Deps., Stanford, spaCy, Google, CoNNL...

Comment: @AlexB. *affigate* et amici are strange.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer with all due respect, Stanford, spaCy, Google, CoNNL is mostly computational linguistics.

Comment: This question page is the #2 google hit for "define affigated". So, I agree, a bit too obscure :) Not in my dictionaries either.

Answer (score 0):

'Derived words' are also used, especially in the context of functional linguistics. In French, we don't use 'complex words' for the words su/pr/in-ffixed, rather we used 'les mots dérivés'. 
You'll find different terminology associated with these, but the standard assumption is that 'affected' 'marked' or 'derived' are always the opposite of 'basic form' 'root form', etc.