# Which part of linguistics concerns/is responsible for "capitalization"?

Tags: orthography

Is it orthography in general, maybe punctuation, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Capitalization is *part of* "orthography in general". Which is usually not considered part of linguistics at all,<sup>1</sup> but can at least be studied in similar ways.<sup>2</sup>

I'm not aware of any formal division of orthography into different areas, but I think in general you'd treat capitalization as a top-level area of study, alongside punctuation, spelling, letter forms, etc., not as part of one of those areas.<sup>3</sup>

Of course there will always be some overlap between the different areas, and some questions where it's not clear where they fall. But let's look at some examples:

- Are "ares" (the plural of "are") and "Ares" (the god of war) homographs? That seems to be a spelling question.
- Which words are capitalized wherever they appear? In English, it's proper names and "I"; in German, it's both common and proper nouns and "Sie".<sup>4</sup> That *might* be a spelling question.<sup>5</sup>
- How are titles capitalized? English capitalizes everything but a closed class of "small words";<sup>6</sup> Spanish treats titles like sentences. That's clearly at a different level than spelling (roughly, phrases, rather than words).
- How are digraphs (that are considered a single letter) capitalized? At first this seems like just a question of letter forms—Dutch has a capital form "IJ" to go with "ij"; Croatian has "Nj" to go with "nj". But when you look at Czech, which capitalizes "ch" as "CH" in some contexts and "Ch" in others, it's clear that there's something else going on here—again, at a higher level than individual letters.

I think that shows that capitalization really is separate enough from other areas of orthography that it's worth treating as its own thing.

---

<sub>1. There are both philosophical and methodological reasons that linguistics studies only, or at least primarily, spoken language, which are too deep to get into here. At any rate, orthography seems to be on-topic for this site, even if it isn't on-topic for many academic linguistics departments.</sub>

<sub>2. As with (spoken) language, it can be studied descriptively—working out the actual rules people use in practice, rather than trying to work out some set of rules from first principles and then prescriptively teaching people to follow those rules. In fact, lexicographers often do an emic descriptive study of the prescriptive rules of both language and orthography; I'm pretty sure Geoffrey Pullum has a good blog post on that somewhere, but I don't remember where.</sub>

<sub>3. For what it's worth, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography) says: "Orthography is largely concerned with matters of spelling, and in particular the relationship between phonemes and graphemes in a language. Other elements that may be considered part of orthography include hyphenation, capitalization, word breaks, emphasis, and punctuation." So, they treat capitalization as one of the top-level areas. But it seems weird that they don't separate out the question of which (variant of which) script a language uses from the question of how phonemes are mapped to graphemes in that script. Wikipedia has articles on the Roman alphabet, the set of CJK characters, etc. independently of articles on individual languages' orthography, and it seems like it would be mad *not* to do that.</sub>

<sub>4. But that's an oversimplification, and in fact the actual rules literate Germans use are not identical to the rules published in the *Reform der deutschen Rechtschreibung von 1996*.</sub>

<sub>5. You can just say "I" is spelled with a capital "I", and "me" is spelled with lowercase "m" and "e". But what about "the lord God" vs. "the god of the hearth", or "President Trump" vs. "a past president"? Unless those are actually separate words, there's more going on than just how each word is spelled.</sub>

<sub>6. … except that there are some cases where people capitalize *all* of the words. For example, album titles almost always do this: *Beat This! The Best Of The English Beat*, *Classic Rock Best Of The Year 2018*, etc. So the rule is more complicated than what you learned in school, and might be worth studying to tease out what it actually is. Which is exactly the same kind of thing linguists do to discover the actual syntactic, etc. rules that speakers use, even if it's not linguistics.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Linguistics itself isn't really concerned with orthography at all, because linguistics aims at describing how natural languages work as they are (**descriptivism**), while orthography is usually understood as imposing rules on how written language *should* work (**prescriptivism**) - of course, as abarnert points out, the real-life application of orthography could also be studied descriptively, but de facto most discussions about orthography revolve around the question how things should be spelled and not on how they are spelled, and that's just what linguistics normally wants to do. Besides that, linguistics primarily focusses on the study of spoken rather than written language; sounds rather than letters are seen as the primary units of language and subject of interest. The comments on [this post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/18824/13238) and [this post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/19012/13238) discuss some reasons why.

Within the field of orthography, capitalization is certainly not part of punctuation, but would probably constitute its own category, alongside

- general rules for the phonemes-to-graphemes (sounds-to-letters) mapping
- exceptions/specific spelling of individual words
- punctuation (where to set commas, quotation marks, apostrophes, etc.)
- separate vs. hyphenated vs. compound spelling
- heuristics for the representation of foreign words and proper names
- and maybe others.

Which precise categories would be seen as basic depends on the language - punctuation is likely a relevant question in pretty much all written languages, whereas e.g. separate vs. compund spelling or capitalizaton is less of an issue in English than it is in German or so.

Comment: You can study orthography descriptively, just as you study (spoken) language descriptively. For example, the actual rules Germans use on the uncommon edge cases to the "capitalize nouns" rule are a perfectly good thing to study, and have been studied. Etymology of modern coinages sometimes involves studying "why is this word spelling this well?" as much as "why is this word pronounced this way?" (especially in Korean and Japanese, but even in English and French). And so on. So, I think your first sentence is either irrelevant or misleading.

Comment: @abarnert I see your point. I modified that statement.

Comment: I think the descriptivism vs. prescriptivism issue is still irrelevant to the question, and to the rest of your answer (which covers the question very nicely). The fact that you can write a prescriptive textbook or usage guide or language standard on orthography doesn't mean orthography is prescriptivism for writing, any more than Strunk & White or the Academie française mean that grammar is prescriptivism for language.

Comment: @abarnert Although the original post was not about the question of descriptivism vs. prescpriptivism, I just felt like I should clarify this because many people seem to have misconceptions about what linguistics is about, as can be seen from the linked quesetions and some others that have been asked on this site. De facto most questions about orthography or language-specific grammar rules *are* about what is the correct standard and not about a descriptive account of the patterns behind this, so I considered it relevant to clarify which of these questions linguistics wants to answer and...

Comment: ... which ones not. As for the second part of your comment, I'm not sure I can agree on that. Even if it's just recommendations/guidelines on how to achieve a particular style and not strict rules on how language must be used, it's still about defining rules of how to express things or a rating of what is "good" style, i.e. establishing rules that should then be followed when producing language, rather than taking the other direction, i.e. first taking actual language, then establishing observations about it and analyzing patterns that may then be written down in a rule-like format, i.e....

Comment: first language then rules. That's what I would call a *pre*scpritivist perspective in contrast to a *de*scpritive one.

Comment: My point isn't that Strunk & White isn't prescriptive—it very much is. My point is that the fact that someone can write a prescriptive guide to grammar doesn't mean that grammar is a prescriptive study. Maybe a better example would have been the Quirk's Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language vs. Huddleston's Cambridge Grammar. The former doesn't mean grammar is a set of prescriptions, the latter doesn't mean it's a set of descriptions, they both mean that grammar is a thing that can be approached either way. Just like orthography (which of course they also both cover).

Comment: Also, Pullum and Huddleston's Student's Introduction and the Miriam-Webster usage guide prove that even student handbooks and style guides can be (productive) written from a descriptive standpoint, not just dictionaries and grammars.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't say either that "grammar is a prescptive study", where did I write something that suggests this? "grammar is a thing that can be approached either way" is just what I meant: It's two different perspectives on the same thing. My point was that (academic) linguistics is interested in the one, but not in the other perspecitve. The two books you mention I don't know so I can't give my own opinition on that; could well be. But this discussion is getting too extensive for the comment section; I'll leave my post as-is now and accept your criticism.

Comment: I didn't say that you said "grammar is a prescriptive study"; I'm assuming that you obviously _don't_ believe it is. My point is that, just as grammar can be (and often is) approached either way, the same is true of orthography. The fact that linguistics studies one but not the other isn't about the descriptive vs. prescriptive question at all. There are good methodological reasons for considering spoken language to be "primary", but that isn't one of them.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but I hope it's not because of my comments. I think the descriptive-prescriptive issue is a distraction, but that hardly makes the answer "not useful or likely to mislead", and beyond that, the answer is right on point, and covers important things that mine doesn't.